# PHP createTextNode with br tag

Tags: php, domdocument, createelement, createtextnode

This is far simpler than I'm making it, I'm sure.
I want to create the code:

```
text<br/>
```

However you cannot use DOMNode::createElement to add node text to a br as you would with a paragraph:

```
$doc->createElement('br',$para->nodeValue)
```

I've also tried creating a text node then adding the break to it. This doesn't work!:

```
$newelement = $doc->createTextNode($para->nodeValue);
$newelement->appendChild($doc->createElement('br'));
$new_node = $para->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $oldelement);
```

Can anyone advise on the correct method for adding a line with a br tag after it?

Comment: perhaps use a document fragment and append to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$frag=$doc->createDocumentFragment();
$br=$doc->createElement('br');
$txt=$doc->createTextNode($para->nodeValue);

$frag->appendChild( $br );
$frag->appendChild( $txt );

/* etc*/
$para->parentNode->appendChild( $frag );
```

Comment: Thank you. This does indeed solve the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer so that others know the question has an answer - but up to you.